# printing data from numpy.ndarray does not work

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, printing

I am trying to read an excel file and print out the content of the file. But I can not print anything, no error, no warnning... nothing...

This is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.set_printoptions(threshold=np.inf)

df = pd.read_excel('tmp.xlsx')
data = df.as_matrix()
data.itemsize

print 'read is done'
```

Any thoughts??

Comment: The only `print` statement in that code is the last one.  If you want to print a variable in a script, you have to use a `print` statement.  E.g. `print data.itemsize`.

Comment: Drop the `printoptions` for now.  What's the purpose of the `data.itemsize` line?  Are you getting `read is done`?

Comment: Thanks @WarrenWeckesser

Answer (score 0):

This code works:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.set_printoptions(threshold=np.inf)

df = pd.read_excel('~/desktop/tmp.xlsx')
data = df.as_matrix()
data.itemsize

print 'read is done'
```

All I've done is changed the path to absolute path. Depending on the system, sometimes you have to do that.

Also when I first exported the file from excel, it had extra columns and rows, and I got an error message. Once those were deleted, it works. I think it's just that you can't have columns with empty headers if the other columns have headers.